# how can I display child details on button click

Tags: reactjs

```
App.js-

class App extends Component{
  render(){
    const data= [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "John Smith",
        email: "jsmith@test.com",
        phone: "123456789",
        details:"john smith details"
        
      }, 
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "ABCD",
        email: "abcd@test.com",
        phone: "987654321"
      },
       {
        id: 3,
        name: "Tyrion",
        email: "tyrion@test.com",
        phone: "123412345"
      },
      ];
  return(
     <div >
      <Customers item={data}  />
     </div>
     
  )
  }
}
export default App;

Customer.js-

class Customers extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
      }
         handleclick= (datalist) => {
            this.setState({
})
     }
    render(){
        const item = this.props.item
         //uses map method 
        const newarray=item.map( (cval)=>{
            return(
            <div>
          <h1>{cval.name}</h1> 
            <p>{cval.email}</p>
            {cval.phone}
            <div>
                <button type='submit' onClick={()=>this.handleclick(cval.id)}>Click to view Details</button>
            </div>
            </div>
            
            )
          })
        return(
            <div>
                {newarray}
                <CustomerList />
            
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Customers;

CustomerList.js-

class CustomerList extends Component{
    render(){
     const datalist=  [
     {
            id: 1,
            name: "John Smith",
            email: "jsmith@test.com",                                       
            phone: "123456789",
            city: "bangalore",
            state: "karnataka",
            country: "India",
            organization: "Company 1",
            jobProfile: "Software Developer",
            additionalInfo: "Has Bought a lot of products before and a high Valu Customer"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'ABCD',
            email: "abcd@test.com",
            phone: "987654321",
            city: "Mangalore",
            state: "karnataka",
            country: "India",
            organization: "Company 2",
            jobProfile: "Software Developer",
            additionalInfo: "Buys Products Rarely"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: "Tyrion",
            email: "tyrion@test.com",
            phone: "123412345",
            city: "Chennai",
            state: "Tamil Nadu",
            country: "India",
            organization: "Company 3",
            jobProfile: "Software Developer",
            additionalInfo: "Buys Lots of Products in general"
        }
    ]
    const newarraydata= datalist.map((val)=>{       
        return(
            <div>
                {val.name}
                {val.email}
                {val.phone}
                {val.city}
                {val.state}
                {val.country}
                {val.organization}
                {val.jobProfile}
                {val.additionalInfo}
            </div>
        )
    })
        return(
                
            <div>
               {newarraydata}
            </div>

        )
    }
}
export default CustomerList;
```

Firstly, I want to display this Customer List details whenever user clicks the button. secondly i dont know what to pass in this.setstate inside handleclclick. I am able to render it normally on screen but don't know how to render it on button click. I am a beginner in reacjs. Your help must be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-https-2i54g?file=/src/App.js

you could use a conditional statement to determine if to render or not;

```
<div>
{cval.id === this.state.currentId && (
        <CustomerList id={this.state.currentId} />
      )}
</div>
```

also you can filter the current selected id by setting state like this

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { currentId: null };
  }

  handleclick = (id) => {
    this.setState({ currentId: id });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Customers component you can use a boolean variable in state "showList" and set it to false initially. Whenever the button is clicked you can change it to true or toggle it based on its current value.
And then inside the render method instead of directly displaying the CustomerList component use conditional rendering to render the component
{this.state.showList ? : null}